# How to access this cell in NPOI?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am using NPOI to create excel sheet using c#. I merged first two rows upto some columns. I am trying to get the next columns second row. See the picture for the reference.
[image]

When I tried with

```
worksheet.GetRow(0)
```

It returned null.

```
worksheet.GetRow(1)
```

is returning a cell. But the value is not showing up. Can anybody tell me, where I am going wrong?

Comment: This won't answer to your question but why don't you use Excel.Interop to create your workbook?

Comment: @XavierAM . The project already used NPOI for most of the parts. If I change the method, then I have to make change in so many places.

Comment: Do you have a little more code than that? I tried to create the same Excel file as you're showing and got cell values for both row 0 and 1.

Comment: @krlzlx Did you access the cell I showed in the picture